# Send message by handler to service

Tags: java, android, service, handler

How I can send message from my activity class? For example, I have some button, and service in another class.

For my button I wrote onCLick() and want do this`

```
Handler h = new Handler();
public void click(Viev v) {
    Mesaage m = new Message();
    m.waht = 11111;
    h.sendMessage(m);
}
```

Something like that, how I can catch that message in service class to start them?

Comment: This is no duplicate. It is another issue.

Comment: @user2335940 Mind if we see what the difference is?